How to address imbalanced work assignments to new boss?
I work as a secondary teacher. This year, my school was assigned a new administrator this summer. Additionally, the school has two teachers per grade level per subject, so I teach half of the cohort, while another teacher has the other half. Both of us have similar seniority.
In checking my roster for the upcoming year, I noticed something strange. Of 30 students with a record of repeated discipline issues, I was assigned 26. Of 34 students with special needs, I was assigned 26. Both of these groups (which have little overlap) take up lots of time, as they require more paperwork, more communication with parents and counselors, hallway chats, legal issues to contend with, record-keeping, regular meetings after school, etc. When spread out across classes, they are less challenging, but as I have the bulk of them, they are in clusters, which only intensifies the challenge.
It would seem to me that someone familiar with the students (not the new admin), or someone friendly with the other grade-level teacher (maybe the new admin), deliberately assigned my co-worker the easiest students and me the headaches.

Am I right in thinking that the statistics are so improbable that I can without a doubt make the accusation that someone deliberately created this list and it was not random?

Am I within my rights to request that they attempt to balance the rosters with the other teacher?

If this were my former admin, I wouldn't hesitate to bring the matter up as I could stand on existing impressions and reputation. But how can I approach an entirely brand new boss with my concern without creating a really bad first impression?



@JoeStrazzere No Joe, no. The first attempted remedy is not to go running to the union and turn everything into a legal mess. That should be one of the last attempted remedies. Everyone needs to put on their adult pants and communicate first...

Is the split of the students the same (or nearly so) for all teacher pairs, or is that split specific to your pair?

Are the classes evenly split by ability?  Or does one class have the "advanced" students who are expected to churn through the subject at a faster speed, and the other have students who will need more time devoted to each new concept?  (i.e. correlation vs causation)

How were these children split last year?  You may have just inherited a problem from someone else.

Your language is very inflammatory - jumping straight to "accusation"s of deliberate biasing of workloads, asking about (legal?) rights, etc. Sure, you can go down that route if you want to, but as you seem to sort of realise in point (3), that's not a good idea.
Instead, try a questioning route.

Hi. I've been looking at the rosters, and it seems I've been assigned the vast majority of the students with discipline issues and special needs. Is there a reason why the assignments were made this way?


That is a more peaceful approach but it has a very high chance of just producing some kind of excuse (which may or may not make sense and be the true reason) and no change in the situation. This approach is only suitable if OP is content with a high probability of no change to the situation.

@quarague This is where you start the conversation. It isn't necessarily where it ends.

At least it's a relatively low-risk "sentinel" question to maybe find out if the situation is due to malicious practice or incompetence. Either of which needs to be dealt with quite differently going further with this.

If you want to be slightly more assertive without being confrontational you can ask "Can we look at balancing out the assignments?" rather than "Is there a reason...?" - that makes it a bit clearer that you're interested in changing the assignments rather than just curious about why they're how they currently are. You might still get the same evasive answer if there's behind-the-scenes politics going on, but if it's a genuine admin error it signals that you'd like it to be reviewed...

Alternatively, ask how the assignments were decided. Maybe there was some reasoning - e.g. placing kids living close together in the same group - that happens to correlate to the mentioned issues.

If I were you, I'd open this answer with a bit of sympathy. In my area, a secondary teacher can sometimes be a challenging job given the intensive care needed for such special groups of students. The OP might very well have just recovered from frustration, and in addition to rational guidance they may need some mental support as well.

@iBug I would say that it is a reality check, and the OP really needs one. Going in with the attitude of the OP is not helpful, and will only serve to inflame discussions they need to have with that administrator.

I am going to first say that I have heard from friends who are Teachers - that some schools can be incredibly Cliquey amongst the Teaching staff - with comparisons being made to the drama that the Students are experiencing with the Drama in the Staff room.
So, it is not entirely implausible that one or more other teachers tried to setup things so that they got the cushy, easy class.
However, for the sake of fairness - there is another explanation, the Heroic explanation - that you are awesome and so were given the tougher students as you were best placed to help them out.
The reality of the question though is that the why of either scenario is irrelevant.
And what I mean by that is this:
As a Teacher and Educator - what is best for the interests of the Students?
I cannot answer that question as I do not know the students nor do I know all the detail as to what disciplinary and what special needs factors there are.
But from my memory of being a school kid - not all factors are created equal. For example if Student A and Student B are in the same class, they might be likely to fight or misbehave, but if they are in separate classes, they don't play off of each other so it is easier for everyone in the class.
This would be my suggestion - sit down and work out what the best for the students combination is - and then approach your Admin team with the proposal and do so on the basis that you are advocating for the students, not yourself

I don't think teachers necessarily need to put up with "what is best for the interests of the Students" in all cases. Even if teacher A is really bad at discipline, that doesn't mean it's OK to dump all the discipline problems on teacher B; and teacher B has a right to be upset about it on his/her own behalf, even if it's not clear that this is worse for the students.

@ruakh - I gotta hard disagree. Would you say that about a Doctor that they should not do what is best for the patient?

Re: "Would you say that about a Doctor that they should not do what is best for the patient?": Yes; see https://www.baizlaw.com/can-doctor-deny-treatment-options/

@ruakh - Again, gotta Hard disagree - look at the reasons why a Doctor may refuse treatment - in almost all cases it is because it is what is best for the patient - however, there are provisions where in Life-death situations, a Doctor may not refuse treatment. They are legally bound to do what is best for the Patient.

I looked at the reasons, and plenty of them are not about what's best for the patient, but rather, about respecting doctors' rights. Re: "in Life-death situations, a Doctor may not refuse treatment": Agreed! But the situation that the OP describes is not a matter of life and death.

@TheDemonLord As a manager of (university) teachers I can tell you that in any profession, no matter whether that's judges, doctors, nurses, teachers, firemen, or policemen, you need to also look at the health and wellness of your staff (as well as on your budget) - and sometimes this means making trade-offs that are to the detriment of some of your "customers". Some teachers are better than others, but you cannot have the best teacher give all the classes. Some teachers are better at handling challenging students, but that does not mean they can handle all problematic students.

@TheDemonLord A "we always do what's best for the [this specific set of] students" mindset sounds great on paper, but is in practice a surefire way to burn out your best teachers. Good teachers consistently get "rewarded" with more and less pleasant work, ultimately leading to a race to the bottom and greatly decreased the quality of your education.

@xLeitix - Suffice to say your statement(s) are one of the problems with Education. I cannot put it any more politely than that.

You seem to have good objective reasoning. I would simply bring that up as-is.

Hey Admin, I have a large amount of very work intensive pupils, can you please restructure the assignment so that they are distributed more equally between myself and colleague XYZ?

Then the ball is in their court, you can then lean back and see what happens. They can't really do more than either accept or deny. If they deny, you can talk further.
Stay on the purely objective/informational level. If necessary, give them the gist the same way you gave it in your question here, and give examples why these pupils, in your experience, require much more time.
Only if and when you gave all your objective arguments and they won't budge, do you have more complicated decisions to take. Until then, I'd relax and work with a good-spirited approach.

I'll address item (1) on the statistics. To make this concrete, I'll assume that there's no overlap between the two categories of difficult students, and that each is assigned by a fair coin-flip to either instructor A or B. So we have a binomial distribution with per-event probability p = 0.5, number of trials n = 30 + 34 = 64, and number of successful events (instructor A gets the difficult student) x = 26 + 26 = 52.
The probability of getting 52 or more such difficult students (P(X) ≥ 52) is calculated at 0.00000022833055 (see here), that is, less than 1 chance in 4 million. For many purposes, any probability less than 0.05 (1 in 20) is considered statistically significant. So this would be considered highly statistically significant, that is, overwhelmingly unlikely to happen by chance with a fair coin.
That said, statistics cannot address the process or mindset of the person(s) who created the list, and even moreso cannot say that any such thing is "without a doubt".

I'd argue that you're misusing statistics if you're applying them to yourself. They're meant to be used for more than a case of 1 and importantly, your personal odds are typically different than another person's odds. For example, the chances of being bitten by a shark are one in three million. The chances of me personally being bitten are zero as I don't live somewhere with sharks. Meanwhile the chances of someone being bitten by a shark when they surf every day in a known area with sharks is much higher than one in three million. Finally, people do get bitten by sharks despite the odds.

@MiniRagnarok You're misusing frequentist statistics if you're applying them to yourself, or to n=1. Bayesian statistics are perfectly comfortable with that. This answer does appear to be using frequentist methods, but the calculations are within an order of magnitude as the Bayesian approach for this problem, so I don't think it's a huge issue.

So if someone in the world got stuck by lightning and made a post here, should we use statistics to explain to him that it was probably intentional ..? People don't post here when things are alright, we're bound to have people that get crappy situations at random. So I agree with MiniRagnarok that stats are misused here, there's no way to get useful data from such process.

@MiniRagnarok The probability that was computed here is 1 in 4 million. It so happens that there are approximately 4 million teachers in total in the US (from quick googling). Your argument would imply that among all the teachers in the US, this post was made by the single most unlucky one among them. Your argument is not wrong as such but the probabilities here are sufficiently extreme to account for sampling bias.

This assumes that the assignments are made entirely randomly. Note that one plausible possibility is that the students have been grouped based on some characteristic (e.g. a measure of past academic attainment, such as test scores) that happens to have a strong correlation with students' personal circumstances.

Relevant xkcd
